# Handling history navigation inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, html5-history

I am building a navigation page that shows some contents inside an `iframe`.
The requirement is that the navigation link that corresponds to the currently loaded page is highlighted. Frame contents is out of my control. Problems begin when the user uses back/forward buttons in his browser.

The idea was to use `history.replaceState` to associate information about navigation link with the page, and to restore navigation panel state on `popstate` event. It worked perfectly in other case when contents  were loaded into the application via AJAX.

In case of `iframe` navigation, `history` object of the top window is not modified, so I ought to work with `contentWindow`, thus limitimg myself fto support only pages from the same domain.

The problem is that I could not subscribe to the event. The following code does not work:

```js
$(window).on('popstate', function () { handleHistory('popstate@window'); });
$('#frame').on('popstate', function () { handleHistory('popstate@iframe'); });
$($('#frame')[0].contentWindow).on('popstate', function () { handleHistory('popstate@iframe.window'); });
$('#frame')[0].contentWindow.onpopstate = function () { handleHistory('popstate@iframe.window'); };
```

In latter case after history navigation `contentWindow.onpopstate` is `null`.

Finally I tried to use the `load` event and it worked, but there is significant delay before it fires as it waits until all page resources would be loaded.

```js
$('#menu a').click(function() {
    // ...
    $('#frame').one('load', function() {
        frameWindow.history.replaceState({ linkId: link.id },frameWindow.document.title, frameWindow.location.href);
    });
    // ...
});
$('#frame').load(function () { handleHistory('load@iframe'); });
```

Another approach I tried was to poll `contentWindow.location.href` in a timer to react earlier. At first glance it worked well, but then I noticed that sometimes history records just disappear from the browser (at least in Firefox).

```js
var isLoading = false;
$('#menu a').click(function() {
    // ...
    isLoading = true;
    $('#frame').one('load', function() { isLoading = false; });
    (function poll () {
        var frameWindow = getFrameWindow();
        if (getFrameWindow().location.href == link.href) {
            frameWindow.history.replaceState({ linkId: link.id },frameWindow.document.title, frameWindow.location.href);
        } else {
            setTimeout(poll, 100);
        }
    })();
    // ...
});
setInterval(function () {
    if (!isLoading) {
        handleHistory('timer');
    }
}, 100);
```

Is there any other good way to track history inside `iframe`? Possibly I made some mistakes? Perhaps there is even a way to do this regardless to content's domain?

---

Here is the source code and demo pages (with delays added to better illustrate script behavior).
onload approach: [src](http://pastebin.com/6TWyQAQw) [demo](http://darkdaskin.tk/question1/nav.html)
timer approach: [src](http://pastebin.com/jzh78pvj) [demo](http://darkdaskin.tk/question1/nav-poll.html)

Comment: same situation here.. did you solve it?

Comment: This worked for me http://www.webdeveasy.com/back-button-behavior-on-a-page-with-an-iframe/

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't a satisfactory solution, but you can examine the size of the history stack in the frame's on load event.

```
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="http://w3c.org" class="xssFrame"></iframe>
<p class="output"></p>

<script>
var size = window.history.length;
var tempSize = null
//document.querySelector(".xssFrame").unload = function(){} //might need to set this handler to force load event on back click
document.querySelector(".xssFrame").onload = function () {
    var delta = size - window.history.length;
    document.querySelector(".output").innerHTML = "parent history: " + size + " combined history: " + window.history.length + " go " + (delta-1).toString()
    if(tempSize ===  window.history.length) {
      document.querySelector(".output").innerHTML = "go now" + (delta).toString()
      window.history.go(delta)
    } else {
      tempSize = window.history.length
    }


}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```