# Prevent navigation in iframe change parent sites history

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, browser

I have a web page where there is an iframe that contains some admin functions.

Now when I navigate (GET and POST requests) in the iframe these actions create entries in browsers history. So now when I want to get to the parent pages previous page it wont happen, because browser (Chrome) starts going back in the iframes history.

So is there a way to overcome this behaviour? I want browsers navigation to work on main page - not in iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no way to prevent browser from maintaining the history but for same origin content you can manipulate the contents of the history.

Basically you can monitor event [`popstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event) and use [`history.replaceState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#the_replacestate()_method) to push your own history that should replace the real history recorded by the browser automatically. Note that you cannot remove items from the history without navigation but you can only replace one item with another.

For an example, see: [Handling history navigation inside iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19452427/334451)

If you don't want to manipulate the history and need to prevent all history maintenance by the browser, you should use only [XHR/ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#the_replacestate()_method) instead of normal links and forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can change you links in the iframe to be something like:

```
href="javascript:location.replace('myurl.html')"
```

Or you can add this at the end of existing iframe html:

```
<script>
  var alist = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < alist.length; ++i) alist[i].setAttribute("href", "javascript:location.replace('" + alist[i].getAttribute("href") + "')";
</script>
```