# Prevent iframe from modifying parents history

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a larger web application (hence it has multiple screens through which a user navigates). In one of the screens I want to embed another page via IFrame from a different origin - I also have no control over the content in the frame. When the IFrame loads it automatically navigates multiple times (front page > single sign on > actual content).

Now when I want to navigate back in the parent application (e.g. using browser buttons) it navigates back within the iframe. So **within the iframe** it navigates back to the sign on page which then immediatly redirecty back to the "actual content". This leaves me stuck with a broken navigation.

Is there a way to prevent that navigation within the iframe affects the parents history? So a "navigate back" event should always caus the parent to navigate back and not the iframe.

There is a related question - unfortunately without a solution: [Prevent navigation in iframe change parent sites history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099961/prevent-navigation-in-iframe-change-parent-sites-history)

Comment: The iframe app is probably checking user cookie or stored token is logged in and redirecting itself. You can't control that. iframe has it's own window isolated from parent window and you can't access it due to same origin policy

Comment: I dont understand how this relates to the question of "how to prevent that the child/iframe modifies the parents history". I do not want to access anything in the iframe (which indeed is not possible due to cross origin)

Comment: What is the actual behavior you would want to see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I also have no control over the content in the frame.

Then you can't.

History records all normal navigation, including inside frames.

The techniques you could use to avoid that require that you replace normal navigation with something else (such as `location.replace()` calls) … but you have to control the page that the navigation takes place from.